# Using DUO Mobile for Enterprise (Work) and Personal Accounts

Tags: multi-factor

As an avid proponent of "don't mix work and pleasure," I have been using Microsoft Authenticator for personal use, and my company uses Duo mobile for enterprise security. This solution is clunky, and I really like the Duo interface much better than Authenticator. How safe is it to use Duo as the sole authenticator for both my work and personal accounts? I am a little bit ignorant to Duo's model, as I am sure someone *somewhere* is paying for it.

My question is:

- Does using Duo mobile for my personal third-party accounts somehow allow my employer to access my 2FA codes for these accounts?

Comment: For #2, that's entirely a licensing question for Duo or your IT team.

Answer (score 0):

The Duo mobile app supports two different kinds of 2FA:

1. Duo authentication - This is the push-notification based authentication that your employer likely uses, and is tied to a specific Duo account.  While there is a free tier and you could, in theory, set it up for personal use, it's squarely targeted at enterprise users and use-cases.
2. TOTP - This is the standard 6-digit rolling code second factor that is supported by tons of services across the web.  These are not tied to a Duo account, and are handled purely on your you device.

---

To directly answer your questions:

1. No, using the Duo mobile app for third-party accounts does not allow your employer to access the codes for those accounts unless you use the app's backup feature to save the secrets for those accounts to an employer-controlled Google drive.
2. Yes, you can use the Duo mobile app for standard TOTP 2FA independently from any Duo account.  Any services that use your employer's Duo account for push-notification based 2FA would stop working though.